# query not resolving right, how to?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query that should return 40 results:

```
$test = mysql_query(" SELECT fname FROM online_all WHERE verify_status = 'v' LIMIT 40 ");
if (!$test ) {print " - Mysql Error - ";echo fns_et_mysql_error(mysql_error());}
```

if i echo `mysql_num_rows($test);` i get `40`. which means that i get the results
but when i print_r `$roww = mysql_fetch_array($test);` i get only one result.

there are no php errors.

Comment: Please spend a bit of time reading the docs, your question is example #2 in http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: What is `fns_et_mysql_error`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop through the results with:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test)) {
    // awesomeness with $row
}
```

Comment: then i could say `$get_roww = $row; print_r ($get_roww);`??

Comment: @Patrioticcow: Read the documentation. There are a million examples there.

Comment: @Patrioticcow: you could do print_r($row) as well!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a loop.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test)){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate the results from the query.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test))
{
  // This is how you print fname.
  echo $row[0];
}
```

Please refer to the documentation where there's also many useful tips of how you can use this function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

You should also know that there exist another useful function for fetching results from mysql queries that fetches results as an associative array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_array returns one row at a time. If you want to loop through all of them you do the following:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($test))
    //Do something
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Check the documentation.  mysql_fetch_array only fetches one row of data at a time.  To get the data for all 40 rows you need a loop (like a for loop conditioned by mysql_num_rows).

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop thru the rows:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test)){
    var_dump($row);
    //etectera
}
```